# Getting the available ranges from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have two tables in oracle sql, A and B that manage a warehouse.

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    id NUMBER ,
    Item_ID NUMBER,
    Start_NUM NUMBER NOT NULL,
    End_NUM NUMBER NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE B (
    id NUMBER ,
    Item_ID NUMBER,
    Start_NUM NUMBER NOT NULL,
    End_NUM NUMBER NOT NULL
); 

INSERT INTO A
(ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM)
VALUES(1, 337, 101, 400);
INSERT INTO A
(ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM)
VALUES(2, 337, 500, 800);
INSERT INTO A
(ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM)
VALUES(3, 337, 801, 1200);
INSERT INTO A
(ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM)
VALUES(4, 337, 1500, 1600);
INSERT INTO A
(ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM)
VALUES(5, 337, 15000, 16000);

INSERT INTO B
(ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM)
VALUES(1, 337, 240, 300);
INSERT INTO B
(ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM)
VALUES(2, 337, 301, 400);
INSERT INTO B
(ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM)
VALUES(3, 337, 850, 1100);
```

Both of them have the same columns
Item_id, Start_num and End_num. Table A has the additions

of the items to the warehouse and table B the consumptions. Start_num and End_num represent the range of items received/consumed respectively.

For example start_num : 101 and end_num: 400 for  item_id 337 means 300 items of id 337 numbering 101,102,103,...,400.

I want to create a view that returns the availability ranges of each item_id based on addition and consumption. For example i received items with numbering 101,102,103,104,...,400 and i consumed the 240,241,...,300 and 301,302,..,400 so the remaining numbering is 101,102,103,...,239.

The result i am looking for looks like that.

| ID | ITEMID | AVAIL_START_NUM | AVAIL_END_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 337 | 101 | 239 |
| 2 | 337 | 500 | 800 |
| 3 | 337 | 801 | 849 |
| 4 | 337 | 1,101 | 1,200 |
| 5 | 337 | 1,500 | 1,600 |
| 6 | 337 | 15,000 | 16,000 |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please describe exactly how each number is calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to merge the consumptions, then find the substracted intervals from intersections with the additions (you may have 2 new intervals) and then add the original additions not having any intersection with the consumptions.

```
WITH data_add(id, item_id, start_num, end_num) AS (
    SELECT 1, 337, 101, 400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 337, 500, 800 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 337, 801, 1200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 337, 1500, 1600 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 337, 15000, 16000 FROM DUAL -- UNION ALL
)
, data_cons(id, item_id, start_num, end_num) AS (
    SELECT 1, 337, 240, 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 337, 301, 400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 337, 850, 1100 FROM DUAL -- UNION ALL
)
, merged_cons(item_id, start_num, end_num) AS (
    SELECT * FROM data_cons
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
        PARTITION BY item_id
        ORDER BY start_num, end_num
        MEASURES FIRST(start_num) AS start_num, LAST(end_num) AS end_num
        PATTERN( merged* strt )
        DEFINE
            merged AS MAX(end_num) + 1 >= NEXT(start_num)
    )
)
, intersections(id, item_id, start_before, end_before, start_after, end_after) AS (
    SELECT a.id, a.item_id, /*a.start_num AS add_start, a.end_num AS add_end, 
        b.start_num AS cons_start, b.end_num AS cons_end, */
        CASE WHEN a.start_num < b.start_num - 1 THEN a.start_num END AS start_before,
        CASE WHEN a.start_num < b.start_num - 1 THEN b.start_num - 1 END AS end_before,
        CASE WHEN b.end_num + 1 < a.end_num THEN b.end_num + 1 END AS start_after,
        CASE WHEN b.end_num + 1 < a.end_num THEN a.end_num END AS end_after
    FROM data_add a
    JOIN merged_cons b
        ON a.item_id = b.item_id AND LEAST(a.end_num, b.end_num) >= GREATEST(a.start_num, b.start_num)
)
SELECT item_id, start_before as start_num, end_before as end_num
FROM intersections WHERE start_before IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT item_id, start_after as start_num, end_after as end_num
FROM intersections WHERE start_after IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT item_id, start_num, end_num
FROM data_add d
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM intersections i WHERE i.id = d.id)
;


337 101 239
337 801 849
337 1101    1200
337 500 800
337 1500    1600
337 15000   16000
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't have an answer but it might help if I share my workings with you.

The issue is how to extract the used stock from the remaining stock and convert the remaining stock into one or more rows - really the problem is with 'more than one' rows.

I'm not sure you will be able to create a view to do this in SQL using the tables as per the design described.  You may need to create a pl/sql procedure to extract the data and use this to create a temp table which will give your stock ranges.

Alternatively, you could create two new tables.  Table newA which has a row for every widget in the range,

```
pk_id, item_id, seq_nbr
n, 337, 101
n+1, 337, 102
.
. etc. until the upper range limit
.
n+x, 337, 400
.
. repeat with all the others...
```

and basically the same idea for the stock in newB which is no longer available...

Then the view would very easy to create, subtracting newB rows from newA rows.

I have my reservations (as an Oracle DBA) about doing it this way, mainly whether it would scale - best have a chat with your own DBA.

A better way would be to have a stock table and just insert and delete rows as needed.

If you do not want to re-write the application you would need some new processes to populate and maintain the two tables, a couple of pl/sql triggers one on each table would probably work.  Is this production?  I ask because if you are in the development stage you would have more options....

Keep in mind it's also possible that my knowledge is insufficient to resolve this task!

I added some extra data to take into account some other range scenarios.

```
select * from V$VERSION;
```

| BANNER | BANNER_FULL | BANNER_LEGACY | CON_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production | Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 21.3.0.0.0 | Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production | 0 |

```
CREATE TABLE A
( id number(10) NOT NULL,
  item_id number(10),
  start_num number(10) not null,
  end_num number(10) not null
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE B
( id number(10) NOT NULL,
  item_id number(10),
  start_num number(10) not null,
  end_num number(10) not null
);
```

```
INSERT INTO A (ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM) VALUES (1, 337, 101, 400);
INSERT INTO A (ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM) VALUES (2, 337, 500, 800);
INSERT INTO A (ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM) VALUES (3, 337, 801, 1200);
INSERT INTO A (ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM) VALUES (4, 337, 1500, 1600);
INSERT INTO A (ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM) VALUES (5, 337, 15000, 16000);
INSERT INTO A (ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM) VALUES (6, 337, 20000, 30000);
INSERT INTO A (ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM) VALUES (7, 444, 20, 30);
select * from a;
```

| ID | ITEM_ID | START_NUM | END_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 337 | 101 | 400 |
| 2 | 337 | 500 | 800 |
| 3 | 337 | 801 | 1200 |
| 4 | 337 | 1500 | 1600 |
| 5 | 337 | 15000 | 16000 |
| 6 | 337 | 20000 | 30000 |
| 7 | 444 | 20 | 30 |

```
INSERT INTO B (ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM) VALUES(1, 337, 240, 300);
INSERT INTO B (ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM) VALUES(2, 337, 301, 400);
INSERT INTO B (ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM) VALUES(3, 337, 850, 1100);
INSERT INTO B (ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM) VALUES(4, 337, 1500, 1510);
INSERT INTO B (ID, ITEM_ID, START_NUM, END_NUM) VALUES(5, 337, 15000, 16000);
select * from b;
```

| ID | ITEM_ID | START_NUM | END_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 337 | 240 | 300 |
| 2 | 337 | 301 | 400 |
| 3 | 337 | 850 | 1100 |
| 4 | 337 | 1500 | 1510 |
| 5 | 337 | 15000 | 16000 |

```
/* 
   assumptions: a.start_num is never be greater then b.start_num
                a.end_num is never less than b.end_num


   this leaves...


*/
select 
  a.item_id as item_num,
  a.start_num as a_start_num,
  a.end_num as a_end_num,
  b.start_num as b_start_num,
  b.end_num as b_end_num
from a 
inner join b 
on a.item_id = b.item_id
  where
    a.start_num <= b.start_num and
    a.end_num >= b.end_num
union
select 
  a.item_id as item_num,
  a.start_num as a_start_num,
  a.end_num as a_end_num,
  b.start_num as b_start_num,
  b.end_num as b_end_num
from a 
left join b
  on a.item_id = b.item_id
  where
   b.item_id is null
;
```

| ITEM_NUM | A_START_NUM | A_END_NUM | B_START_NUM | B_END_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 337 | 101 | 400 | 240 | 300 |
| 337 | 101 | 400 | 301 | 400 |
| 337 | 801 | 1200 | 850 | 1100 |
| 337 | 1500 | 1600 | 1500 | 1510 |
| 337 | 15000 | 16000 | 15000 | 16000 |
| 444 | 20 | 30 | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LPAsiLIP)

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. It definitely helped me !!